# How do I retrieve what application/servicePrincipal a user is allowed access to from AzureAD Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have credentials for a tenant that is not home. To get access to applications, I need to be in the home tenant, which is why I am getting only a part of the actual applications list all over. But I managed to pull all of them by understanding the concept of service principals.

The next problem is.. How can I access which users are allowed access to these applications/servicePrincipals?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: Too late to comment, but thank you! No concerns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api)

> We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD
>   Graph API to access Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) resources.

We can [list the owners for an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but there is no api to retrieve the applications a user is allowed to access. Also, the application admin/global admin have access to all the applications.

[image]